# meaning of *= in the below snippet in SCSS

Tags: sass

I am new to scss. What is the meaning of *= in the below code ?

```
div[class*="SnackbarItem-contentRoot"] {
    width: 600px;
    &[class*="SnackbarItem-variantError"]{
        background-color: $orange;
        color: $white;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*=` is not SCSS features, it is an attribute selectors used in CSS.

For example, this will select all `a` element with **href** attribute whose value contains at least one occurrence of **example** and apply **font size to 2em**

```css
a[href*="example"] {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

In our case, `*=` means get all div with class whose value contains at least one occurrence of **"SnackbarItem-contentRoot"**

However `&`, a parent selector invented by Sass that’s used in nested selectors.
`&[class*="SnackbarItem-variantError"]` means get all div with class whose value contains at least one occurrence of **"SnackbarItem-contentRoot"**

Your can find more information about attribute selectors [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)

Answer (score 1):

```
    > This is CSS Attribute Selector.
    
It is used to select all html elements whose Attribute or class Attribute is "className" or html Attribute name.
    where * means 'All' and '=' match Attribute value.
 
   e.g - it select all div whose className is 'SnackbarItem-contentRoot'
      div[class*="SnackbarItem-contentRoot"] {
       background: yellow;
       width:600px;
      }
    So, you can use this selector in css as well as in scss file.
```